Не работет бот на vkbottle
Проблема заключается в том что я только знакомлюсь с библиотеками ВК и мне посоветовали эту библиотеку, я смотрел во всех документациях которые нашел правила написания но видимо все таки сделал что-то не так
from vkbottle.bot import Bot, Message
from config import tokens
from loguru import logger

logger.disable('vkbottle')

bot = Bot(token=tokens)

@bot.on.private_message(text="start")
async def start(message: Message):
    await message.answer("Привет")

bot.run_forever()

Ошибки:

    Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-1' coro=<Bot.run_polling() done, defined at C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\vkbottle\framework\bot\bot.py:77> exception=TypeError("VKAPIError.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'error_subcode'")>
Traceback (most recent call last):
   
File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\vkbottle\framework\bot\bot.py", line 81, 
in run_polling
    async for event in polling.listen():
   
File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\vkbottle\polling\bot_polling.py", line 57, in listen
    server = await self.get_server()
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  
File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\vkbottle\polling\bot_polling.py", line 52, in get_server
    return (await self.api.request("groups.getLongPollServer", {"group_id": self.group_id}))[
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  
File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\vkbottle\api\api.py", line 79, in request    return await self.validate_response(method, data, response)  # type: ignore
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  
File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\vkbottle\api\api.py", line 103, in validate_response
    response = await validator.validate(method, data, response, self)  # type: ignore
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  
File "C:\Users\Acer TM8372\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\vkbottle\api\response_validator\vk_api_error_validator.py", line 48, in validate
    raise VKAPIError[code](**error)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  
File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\vkbottle\exception_factory\code_exception.py", line 26, in __call__
    return super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

TypeError: VKAPIError.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'error_subcode'




Дополните свой вопрос информацией о том, как устанавливали библиотеку.

Самой обычной командой pip install vkbottle

Значит, попробуйте удалить библиотеку и установить стабильный релиз (команда в моём ответе).

Я думаю что проблема не с кодом, а с библиотекой (все ошибки туда ведут).
Попробуйте установить стабильный релиз pip install vkbottle==2.7.12,
Установите uvloop и loguru с помощью команд:


pip install loguru
pip install uvloop


И любую библиотеку для ускорения json из:

ujson, hyperjson, orjson

Эта информация доступна на VkBottle
